# Incorrect results in mvn dependency:analyze

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I've been searching for a tool, which is able to show you unused dependecies. I soon stumbled over the maven command `mvn dependency:analyze`. The problem with this is, that it often detects "unused" dependencies which let the build fail if missing.

Here is an example from an optimized Project:

```
$ mvn dependency:analyze

[INFO] Building LogfileTool 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze (default-cli) > test-compile @ LogfileTool >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ LogfileTool ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ LogfileTool ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Projects\LogfileToolMa\LogfileTool\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ LogfileTool ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Projects\LogfileToolMa\LogfileTool\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ LogfileTool ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze (default-cli) < test-compile @ LogfileTool <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze (default-cli) @ LogfileTool ---
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    log4j:apache-log4j-extras:jar:1.2.17:compile
[WARNING]    org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.18:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Dependencies in Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

<!-- Logger -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Generating Getter, Setter etc. -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.16.18</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The used Packages of Lombok are:

```
lombok.AccessLevel
lombok.Data
lombok.Getter
lombok.Setter
```

By Removing lombok from my POM i get the following Error by Buildig the Project

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[7,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[8,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[9,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[10,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[26,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Data
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[13,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[14,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[15,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[16,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[26,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Data
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[34,4] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Getter
  location: class  ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[35,4] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Setter
  location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[35,4] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Getter
  location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[36,4] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Setter
  location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[62,7] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setXmlToRead(java.lang.String)
  location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[63,7] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setPathToLogfiles(java.lang.String)
  location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[63,7] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setPathForStorage(java.lang.String)
  location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[64,7] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setPathToLogfile(java.lang.String)
  location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/log_handler/LogfileReader.java:[93,50] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPathToLogfiles()
  location: variable logfileSearchConfig of type ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/log_handler/LogfileReader.java:[95,100] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getXmlToRead()
  location: variable logfileSearchConfig of type ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/Main.java:[61,51] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPathToLogfile()
  location: variable logfileToolConfig of type ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/Main.java:[71,52] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPathForStorage()
  location: variable logfileToolConfig of type ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
22 errors 
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.747 s
Finished at: 2017-09-27T10:04:20+02:00
Final Memory: 14M/210M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project LogfileTool: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[7,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[8,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[9,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[10,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[26,2] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Data
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[13,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[14,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[15,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[16,14] package lombok does not exist
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[26,2] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Data
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[34,4] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Getter
location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[35,4] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Setter
location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[35,4] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Getter
location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[36,4] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Setter
location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[62,7] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method setXmlToRead(java.lang.String)
location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileSearchConfig.java:[63,7] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method setPathToLogfiles(java.lang.String)
location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[63,7] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method setPathForStorage(java.lang.String)
location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/config_handler/LogfileParseConfig.java:[64,7] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method setPathToLogfile(java.lang.String)
location: class ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/log_handler/LogfileReader.java:[93,50] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getPathToLogfiles()
location: variable logfileSearchConfig of type ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/log_handler/LogfileReader.java:[95,100] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getXmlToRead()
location: variable logfileSearchConfig of type ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileSearchConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/Main.java:[61,51] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getPathToLogfile()
location: variable logfileToolConfig of type ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
ch/glue/logfiletool/logfiletool/Main.java:[71,52] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getPathForStorage()
location: variable logfileToolConfig of type ch.glue.logfiletool.logfiletool.config_handler.LogfileParseConfig
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And without log4j-extras i get following Error by running the Project

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
```

Both log4j and lombok are used in my Project. Do you have an Idea how to fix this or where this is comming from?

thank you in advance

Comment: The first thing is to use a most recent version of [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). Furthermore the question is how those dependencies are being used?

Comment: I believe the analyzer runs at bytecode level so it may not detect something like lombok being unused as it's already compiled.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the scopes? Can log4j-extras be a runtime dependency? Not familiar with lombok and how that might be resolved

Comment: @VivekChavda i have not modified the scope since the Code is working

Comment: @Cruxlp By any chance do you have a .xml or .properties which has log4j configuration mentioning RollingFileAppender and that is configured as default log configuration in your code?

Comment: @nullpointer yes i have a log4j.properties file

Comment: That's the cause then. Since your java classes wouldn't be making use of that class but when you configure the logger that would require them. Not sure why dependency plugin doesn't confirm to this. @khmarbaise Can help here probably.

Comment: @nullpointer what about lombok?

Comment: @Cruxlp The error as shared by you doesn't list lombok as one.

Comment: @Cruxlp almost same reason `LogfileSearchConfig` from lombok is in use in your project.

Comment: @nullpointer LogfileSearchConfig is one of my Java-Classes

Comment: @Cruxlp Which uses a package from `lombok` either an unused import OR you can find what actually are you using there in the class and list that in question as well.

Comment: @Cruxlp `lombok.AccessLevel` usages in your code should let you know if lombok is required or not.

Comment: @nullpointer it is required

Comment: @Cruxlp strange in that case that the dependency plugin lists it out as Unused. Could you try to rebuild your project with maven-dependency-plugin 3.0.2 and update the question further.

Comment: @nullpointer why should i try to rebuild it with an older version of maven?

Comment: @Cruxlp Not an older version of maven but the latest version of the plugin...from your logs `maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze`... hence update in your `pom.xml` > `<build>` ~> `<plugins>` make sure you have an entry for this plugin with `3.0.2` version

Comment: I changed the version and got the same error as before. @nullpointer

Comment: Not much I can help with in that case. The dependencies shouldn't be listed as unused if they are used.

Comment: "i have not modified the scope since the Code is working" The code can work but the dependencies may not be scoped properly. For example, if you are only using some dependency during testing, you can still declare it as scope 'compile' and maven will build and run fine. But the dependency plugin will warn you that it's unused, because none of the production code is calling into that test dependency.

Comment: @khmarbaise - If you enter "use the latest version" as an answer (rather than just a comment), I will upvote it. #points

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have also been running into the issue where project Lombok has been marked by `dependency:analyze` as an Unused declared dependency. Project Lombok does most of its magic compile time, and as such most annotations are removed after compilation. This is why Maven's dependency analyzer does not recognize it. And why it also fails to detect dependencies that are loaded using [SPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html).

We have worked around this by explicitly telling the Dependency analyzer plugin to ignore Project Lombok. This can be done with the `<usedDependency>` configuration option, or the more fine-grained `<ignoreUnusedDeclaredDependency>` as such:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
                    <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>org.projectlombok:lombok</ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>
                </ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

PS regarding scopes: Lombok is a compile time dependency, but need not be on the classpath at runtime (or end up in your lib folder). The `provided` dependency states that the jar should be present for compilation, but at run-time it is expected to be provided by the runtime environment (e.g. the container you run it in). Since Lombok is not needed at runtime, there will be no problems when your runtime does not provide Lombok, contrary to what you'd expect from the Maven dependency declaration.